# EnhancerByGuice generated class causing error with Dropwizard when adding a custom annotation and MethodInterceptor

Tags: java, java-8, jersey, guice, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard application with following resource file:

```
@Path("/v1/")
@Api("Static Resources")
@Slf4j
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Singleton
public class StaticResourcesImpl implements StaticResources {

    @Inject private SomeService someService;    

    @GET
    @Path("/help/{id}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Give a Help page", response = Help.class)
    //@Action(action = "getHelp")
    public Response getHelp(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        try {
            return Response.ok(someService.read(id)).build();
        } catch (NotFoundException e){
            log.warn("Exception in reading Help for id: " + id, e );
            return Response.status(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
        }
    }
```

This has been registered to `jersey` like following:

```
environment.jersey().register(injector.getInstance(StaticResources.class));
```

Above works.

But If I create one custom annotation and add to resource (above commented before `getHelp` method):

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
/**
 * This annotation is intended to be used on a method with an ActionName
 */
public @interface Action {
    String action();
}
```

and add a method interceptor via `bindInterceptor`, like following:

```
requestStaticInjection(MyInterceptor.class);
bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(Action.class), new MyInterceptor());
```

where `MyInterceptor` looks like following:

```
public class MyInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    @Inject
    private static myService MyService;

    @Override
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
        Action action = methodInvocation.getMethod().getAnnotation(Action.class);            
            if(myService.my Condition(authRequest)) {
                return methodInvocation.proceed();
            }
        }
        return myError;
    }
```

When I try to run this, I get following error:

> [[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.abc.demo.apis.usecase.resources.impl.StaticResourcesImpl.getHelp() and public final javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.abc.demo.apis.usecase.resources.impl.StaticResourcesImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$69175a50.getHelp() at matching regular expression /contents/formats. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.;

detailed stacktrace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: io.dropwizard.jersey.setup.JerseyServletContainer-e0f2686@72f166ff==io.dropwizard.jersey.setup.JerseyServletContainer,jsp=null,order=1,inst=false
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.doStart(InstrumentedHandler.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.doStart(StatisticsHandler.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:53)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:44)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:87)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
    at com.abc.demo.apis.Boot.main(Boot.java:111)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.abc.demo.apis.usecase.resources.impl.StaticResourcesImpl.getHelp() and public final javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.abc.demo.apis.usecase.resources.impl.StaticResourcesImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$69175a50.getHelp() at matching regular expression /contents/formats. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; 
    source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@330d557e', source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@439047ef']
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:553)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:348)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:345)
```

Following are the dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.smoketurner</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8-1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
                <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
                <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
                <artifactId>metrics-annotation</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-migrations</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
                <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hubspot.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-guice</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.4.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-jackson</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-jersey</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-jetty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-lifecycle</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
                <artifactId>dropwizard-servlets</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
                <artifactId>metrics-healthchecks</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.palominolabs.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
                <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
                <artifactId>metrics-healthchecks</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-forms</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>flipkart.feeds</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <!--<scope>compile</scope>-->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
                <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>24.1.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
        <artifactId>metrics-annotation</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

Not able to understand why this should cause any issue and how to resolve this, change few things here and there but did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly the same issue, but I've seen some weird stuff with Guice and interceptors where Exceptions don't match what is actually going on.  In my particular case the exception was different, but the underlying issue was that the `@Inject` fields of my intercepter were not being injected.

So my interceptor was throwing a NullPointerException but my Api was seeing some other random exception from another interceptor above it.  We had to resolve the underlying (hidden) NPE, so instead of :

```
bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(Action.class), new MyInterceptor());
```

I had to put:

```
ServiceInfoInterceptor siInterceptor = new ServiceInfoInterceptor();
requestInjection(siInterceptor);
bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(ServiceInfo.class), siInterceptor);
```

Which caused my ServiceInfoInterceptor to have non null members, clearing up the NullPointerException and clearing up the other random exception that was being thrown in it's place.

Comment: this did not work for me, besides `requestInjection(siInterceptor);` does not compile. this has to be: `requestStaticInjection(ServiceInfoInterceptor.class);`